# How can I get Magnet links to open in transmission when running Enlightenment as my Window Manager?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, enlightenment

I have found a way to do it when running Gnome, but I don't know how in Enlightment, and I'd really prefer not to switch window managers.  The OS is Mint 12.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the file `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/magnet=chromium.desktop
```

This registers the application *chromium* to handle magnet links.

Comment: This doesn't work, and isn't what I'd asked to do.  I wanted to know how to open the files in Transmission when using Chrome, this just opened a blank new tab.  I've since switched to using Firefox, which opens them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the file `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/magnet=transmission-gtk.desktop
```

This registers the application *transmission-gtk* to handle magnet links.